# Several L-functions but one Galois representation: How to choose

Tags: automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-conjectures, shimura-varieties

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a reductive group which enjoys all the nice properties a reducive group can dream of. Fix $(\mathbf{G},X)$ a Shimura datum associated with it and assume that if $K\leq\mathbf{G} $ is neat then the locally symmetric space associated has a model $S_{K}$ over the reflex field.

We then conjecture that in the case of a cuspidal cohomological representation of $\mathbf{G}$ of level $K$, the Galois representation given by the Langlands correspondence is (perhaps up to a certain multiplicity) the Galois-module part of the $\pi$-isotypic component of the cohomology of $S_{K}$, and it is a theorem in some examples of group $\mathbf{G}$.

But the L function of a cuspidal representation depends on the choice an embeding $\mathbf{G}^{L}\overset{r}{\rightarrow} \mathbf{Gl}_{n}$, and the former Galois representation do not depend on such choice.

This observation suggests that there should be a canonical choice of $r$, right?

I convinced myself before that the convention was to choose the L-function wich appear in the Hasse-Weil zeta function of $S_{K}$, but recently I understood that the Hasse-Weil zeta function of $S_{K}$ is difficult to compute.

**Question** How to choose $r$? Is it related to the Hasse-Weil zeta function of $S_{K}$?

**Question** Any references?

Comment: Up to details, $r$ is essentially the representation of $\hat{G}$ whose highest weight is given by the Hodge cocharacter of the chosen Shimura datum (which you need to specify beyond just fixing $G$, btw...). This was discovered by Langlands a long time ago while he was standing outside smoking a cigarette in Bonn (see the long commentary on the letter to Lang here: https://publications.ias.edu/rpl/section/26). For a precise statement, try to read about the "Arthur-Kottwitz conjecture". Johansson-Thorne is a nice modern reference for this. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that my answer is a bit anachronistic: Langlands's nicotine-influenced insight predated the modern definition of a Shimura datum, which explains why he mentions finding the relevant $r$'s on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank's a lot. This is a very nice answer (wich could be I think an actual answer by the way, but that is up to you).